# Change hadoop version using spark-ec2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, spark-ec2

I want to know is it possible to change the hadoop version when the cluster is created by spark-ec2?

I tried

```
spark-ec2 -k spark -i ~/.ssh/spark.pem -s 1 launch my-spark-cluster
```

then I login with

```
spark-ec2 -k spark -i ~/.ssh/spark.pem login my-spark-cluster
```

and found out the hadoop version is 1.0.4.

I want to use 2.x version of hadoop, what's the best way to do configure this?

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported, though there is an [open PR to add support for launching Hadoop 2 clusters](https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/pull/77).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Hadoop 2.0

`spark-ec2` script doesn't support **modifying** existing cluster but you can **create** a new Spark cluster with Hadoop 2.

See this excerpt from the script's `--help`:

```
  --hadoop-major-version=HADOOP_MAJOR_VERSION
                    Major version of Hadoop (default: 1)
```

So for example:

```
spark-ec2 -k spark -i ~/.ssh/spark.pem -s 1 --hadoop-major-version=2 launch my-spark-cluster
```

..will create you a cluster using current version of Spark and Hadoop 2.

If you use Spark v. 1.3.1 or Spark v. 1.4.0 and will create a standalone cluster then you will get [**Hadoop v. 2.0.0 MR1**](https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/blob/v4/spark/init.sh#L105-118) (from Cloudera Hadoop Platform 4.2.0 distribution) this way.

The caveats are:

- some features are not yet supported with this Hadoop version because of bugs - [for example there is a problem with using Tachyon](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3185),
- although in theory in Spark 1.4.0 [you can create a YARN cluster using spark-ec2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3674) its [not documented yet] as of June 2015 and our tries to use it have failed,

..but I have **successfully** used a few clusters of Spark 1.2.0 and 1.3.1 created with Hadoop 2.0.0, using some Hadoop2-specific features. (for Spark 1.2.0 with a few tweaks, that I have put in my forks of [Spark](https://github.com/grzegorz-dubicki/spark) and [spark-ec2](https://github.com/grzegorz-dubicki/spark-ec2), but that's another story.)

## Hadoop 2.4, 2.6

If you need **Hadoop 2.4** or **Hadoop 2.6** then I would currently (as of June 2015) recommend you to create a standalone cluster manually - it's easier than you probably think.

Comment: Hello Greg, are you still not recommending using spark-ec2 scripts to launch hadoop 2.6 ?

Comment: Hi @dirceusemighini! I haven't been working on it since June 2015, so Spark v. 1.4.0 and as of March 2016 we have v. 1.6.1 stable, so unfortunately I don't have an up to date opinion as of now.